# Words with different meaning than root words

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the term for words that have different meaning than their root words? For example moon+shine = moonshine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A phrase whose meaning is different from a combination of its constituents?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137509/a-phrase-whose-meaning-is-different-from-a-combination-of-its-constituents) The descriptor for similar compounds is identical; they are **non-compositional**.